# Do Taylor vortices occur on a cylinder rotating in an infinite fluid (i.e., an infinitely wide gap Couette flow)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If a cylinder rotates about its axis in an infinite fluid will instabilities occur on the cylinder's surface?

Comment: What does the Taylor number criterion tell you?